# We get the following error in Robot Framework "Keyword 'OperatingSystem.Create File' got positional argument after named arguments"

Tags: python, robotframework

The below robot framework keywords were used in one of our test cases:

```
${data_dict}=    Create Dictionary    apiproxy    ${APIPROXY}    request_verb    ${REQUEST_VERB}    basepath    **${basepath}**    pathsuffix    **${pathsuffix}**  

${data_file}=    generate data    ${data_dict}  

Create File    test.sh    content=${QPID_COMMAND}  ${QPID} -org ${ORG} -env ${ENVIRONMENT} -exchange ${exch_name} -queue ${queue_name} -useProtoBuf -noOfMessages  ${msg_count} -batchsize 1 -config ${data_file}
```

Here the value of `${basepath}`:

`${basepath} = ${EMPTY}  and ${pathsuffix} = /testpath/`

When I try to run this, the error `"Keyword 'OperatingSystem.Create File' got positional argument after named arguments"` is displayed. I was not able to access the Robot framework Docs.

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you marked up the test data as code so we can more easily see boundaries between cells in a row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What the error literally means is that you can't put named arguments (eg: `x=y`) before positional arguments. In the code you show in your question you are giving the keyword a named argument of `content=${QPID_COMMAND}` followed by another argument that begins with `${QPID}`.

Could it be that you have a typo, and that there shouldn't be two spaces between those two? Robot is seeing those two spaces before `${QPID}` as a column separator, so it thinks `${QPID}` is a separate argument rather than as part of the content.